# Foreign key constraint vs. separate table (Relational DBs) for 1-to-n and n-to-1

Tags: performance, hibernate, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, relational-algebra

Here's a design question. I'm very interested since there is a performance impact, however, do we have one when it comes to understandability or semantics?

I've seen a lot of people - especially in enterprise environments - letting Hibernate generate separate tables, instead of creating foreign key constraints.

In particular, if you have Table A and Table B, and the relationship is 1-to-many, then people tend to let Hibernate generate the table Table A_B which contains the primary keys of A and B, and which exhibits the 1-to-many relationship. More specifically, they extract the foreign key constraint into a new - and separate - table.

1) From a performance perspective this isn't so fortunate, extra-table (more memory) and usually more joins are needed, which may negatively impact performance. Of course, it depends on the underlying implementation, because with caching and smart cursor management this can be mitigated.

2) Is the semantics and/or understandability affected? If so, what about the rule never to look at generated code? (advocates of code generation will give a categorical NO). This only applies if you generate your tables from a model (like Hibernate allows you to do).

3) Normal forms are not affected by this way of designing your tables, however, it does contribute to the "explosion of tables" as you try to impose higher normal forms.

I really do not understand whether there is a hidden meaning to this "best practice" (if it is one), or if it's just a mistake/lack of understanding in configuring Hibernate ;-).

Any and all opinions are more than welcome!

EDIT: The tables/relations are NOT n-to-m (many-to-many). Also, you can let Hibernate generate a relation instead of a foreign key constraint, my question (the one above) is why would you do that?!

Comment: If you have a mapping table (`A_B` in your example) it is more likely to be a many-to-many relationship, not a 1-to-many.

Comment: I've double-checked, they're ALL 1-to-many and many-to-1. That was actually part of the question, why do people do this?

Comment: I'd say in that case there is probably something wrong with your Hibernate mapping (I don't really know Hibernate though). Why don't you add the mapping to the question.

Comment: As stated in the question, you can opt (mark a check-box to be precise) on whether to generate a relation or not. The question remains, why did the developers of Hibernate envisage such a case? And why are some people opting for this option, that to me, looks very useless. To be precise, I'm interested in hearing a valid use case and the arguments for making such a decision.

Comment: P.S. I suspect it is a misconfiguration or a lack of understanding of how to configure Hibernate. However, before I tell them their design is not OK, I would rather hear some opinions from other developers. In any case, thank you for your contribution.

P.P.S. Non-disclosure agreements do not permit me to publish the model, however, the problem is exactly as stated in the question. And it's the same for most of the relations in our model.

Comment: Not knowing Hibernate, but is this possibly just Hibernate's (alternative) means to creating a non-clustered index on the foreign key?

Comment: I just checked my stupid hibernate schema and hibernate mapped 1:n as expected (no extra table). So those people must do it on purpose. Why don't you just ask one of those people?